# Finding Stack Trace in Eclipse with Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, stack-trace

Not used to using Eclipse for java, mainly used jEdit but with the Android dev along comes Eclipse. I've switched to the debug window and pressed the debug button which starts my app, It crashes however I can't find the stack trace. I can see in the 'Debug' pane that it has crashed with a '' exception however I can't see any more information. Not sure if you can get it but I'm a little used to Visual Studio with line numbers and a bit more information saying what went wrong. As I said all I'm getting is -

```
 'Thread [<1> main](Suspended (exception RuntimeException))'
```

in the debug window. Can anyone shed some light as to where I can find more information?

Answer (score 6):

For normal Java development in Eclipse, stack traces will appear in console view:

```
Window -> Show view -> Console
```

(if it isn't listed, click on "Other" and find "Console").

When dealing with Android development, find the `"LogCat"` view, like I described above. The stack trace should be there.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the DDMS perspective and LogCat view. Android logs everything, what can be viewed with LogCat.

Answer (score 4):

You should read this guide: [Debugging Android using Eclipse and ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can directly type the **`adb logcat`** at the command prompt, it will display the stack traces.

For more info, refer this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat

Comment: how can I find the stacktrace.where I have to type the e.printStackTrace(); can you tell me

Comment: @Steph read [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) document.