# importing a raw mp3 resource for mediaplayer

Tags: android, resources, media-player

I am trying to play a simple mp3 file with the following code:

```
package swalehm.android.examples.myTest1;
import swalehm.android.examples.myTest1.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myTest1Main extends Activity 
{
    Context context;

   public MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Hello, Android");
        setContentView(tv);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

I have added a folder named 'raw' in the 'res' folder and the file sound1.mp3 is in it.

I checked R.java. The named resource sound1 does exist in that file. However, when 
I build it, I get an error saying sound1 cannot be resolved or is not a field. I went through the forum and saw a suggestion to remove android.R from the imprts. now i get a error saying:

The method `MediaPlayer(myTest1Main, int)` is undefined for the type `myTest1Main`.

Comment: Put start() on onCreat() is a BAD idea: just rotate the screen and the music could (depending manifest config) start again...and again ... with superposition

Comment: Note: in some contexts, use this will not work for context. Then you should use getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
public MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
```

Comment: Hi Rajath

Thanks for your help. I must have screwed that line up while trying different things. I did manage to build the app. But when it starts running on the emulator it gives me the following error: 

The Application Hello Android (process swalehm.andorid.examples.helloAndroid) has stopped unexpectdely. please try again

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Swalehm

Comment: Sorry I have to ask What the same question what is a stack trace. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Well, your application crashes, right? So, in the logcat, search for the list of functions that lead up to the crash. If you're using Eclipse, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957730/finding-stack-trace-in-eclipse on how to do that.