# in android how can i get screenshot or bitmap from custom surface view

Tags: android

i am creating android application and i need to take bitmap from my frame layout which contains imageview and second is custom surface view the xml file is as below but when i try to make screen short from frame layout i am getting only bitmap of below image not of above image can any one tall me how can i get the bitmap of all fram layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frmQueue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imglow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <com.winsontan520.WScratchView
            android:id="@+id/scratch_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

WScratchView.java

```
public class WScratchView extends SurfaceView implements IWScratchView, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "WScratchView";

// default value constants
private final int DEFAULT_COLOR = 0xff444444; // default color is dark gray
public static  int DEFAULT_REVEAL_SIZE = 30;

public static final int DEFAULT_SCRATCH_TEST_SPEED = 4;
private Context mContext;
public Bitmap mbits;
private WScratchViewThread mThread;
List<Path> mPathList = new ArrayList<Path>();
public int mOverlayColor;
public Paint mOverlayPaint;
public int mRevealSize;
private boolean mIsScratchable = true;
private boolean mIsAntiAlias = false;
private Path path;
private float startX = 0;
private float startY = 0;
private boolean mScratchStart = false;
public Bitmap mScratchBitmap;
public Drawable mScratchDrawable = null;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
private Matrix mMatrix;
private Bitmap mScratchedTestBitmap;
public Canvas mScratchedTestCanvas;
private OnScratchCallback mOnScratchCallback;

//Enable scratch all area if mClearCanvas is true
private boolean mClearCanvas = false;
//Enable click on WScratchView if mIsClickable is true
private boolean mIsClickable = false;

public WScratchView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(ctx, attrs);
    init(ctx, attrs);
}

public WScratchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    mContext = context;

    // default value
    mOverlayColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    mRevealSize = DEFAULT_REVEAL_SIZE;

    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.WScratchView, 0, 0);

    final int indexCount = ta.getIndexCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < indexCount; i++) {
        int attr = ta.getIndex(i);
        if (attr == R.styleable.WScratchView_overlayColor) {
            mOverlayColor = ta.getColor(attr, DEFAULT_COLOR);
        } else if (attr == R.styleable.WScratchView_revealSize) {
            mRevealSize = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, DEFAULT_REVEAL_SIZE);
        } else if (attr == R.styleable.WScratchView_antiAlias) {
            mIsAntiAlias = ta.getBoolean(attr, false);
        } else if (attr == R.styleable.WScratchView_scratchable) {
            mIsScratchable = ta.getBoolean(attr, true);
        } else if (attr == R.styleable.WScratchView_scratchDrawable) {
            mScratchDrawable = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.WScratchView_scratchDrawable);
        }
    }

    setZOrderOnTop(true);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

    mOverlayPaint = new Paint();
    mOverlayPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
    mOverlayPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mOverlayPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mOverlayPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

    // convert drawable to bitmap if drawable already set in xml
    if (mScratchDrawable != null) {
        mScratchBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mScratchDrawable).getBitmap();
    }

    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setDither(true);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //Clear all area if mClearCanvas is true
    if(mClearCanvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
        return;
    }

    if (mScratchBitmap != null) {
        if (mMatrix == null) {
            float scaleWidth = (float) canvas.getWidth() / mScratchBitmap.getWidth();
            float scaleHeight = (float) canvas.getHeight() / mScratchBitmap.getHeight();
            mMatrix = new Matrix();
            mMatrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mScratchBitmap, mMatrix, mBitmapPaint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(mOverlayColor);
    }

    for (Path path : mPathList) {
        mOverlayPaint.setAntiAlias(mIsAntiAlias);
        mOverlayPaint.setStrokeWidth(mRevealSize);

        canvas.drawPath(path, mOverlayPaint);
    }


}

private void updateScratchedPercentage() {
    if(mOnScratchCallback == null) return;
    mOnScratchCallback.onScratch(getScratchedRatio());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    synchronized (mThread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
        if (!mIsScratchable) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (me.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
            startX = me.getX();
            startY = me.getY();
            mPathList.add(path);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mScratchStart) {
                path.lineTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
            } else {
                if (isScratch(startX, me.getX(), startY, me.getY())) {
                    mScratchStart = true;
                    path.lineTo(me.getX(), me.getY());
                }
            }
            updateScratchedPercentage();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //Set call back if user's finger detach
            if(mOnScratchCallback != null){
                    mOnScratchCallback.onDetach(true);  
            }
            //perform Click action if the motion is not move
            //and the WScratchView is clickable
            if(!mScratchStart && mIsClickable){
                post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        performClick();
                    }
                });
            }
            mScratchStart = false;
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean isScratch(float oldX, float x, float oldY, float y) {
    float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oldX - x, 2) + Math.pow(oldY - y, 2));
    if (distance > mRevealSize * 2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    mThread = new WScratchViewThread(getHolder(), this);
    mThread.setRunning(true);
    mThread.start();

    mScratchedTestBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(arg0.getSurfaceFrame().width(), arg0.getSurfaceFrame().height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mScratchedTestCanvas = new Canvas(mScratchedTestBitmap);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    boolean retry = true;
    mThread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            mThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing but keep retry
        }
    }

}

class WScratchViewThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private WScratchView mView;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    public WScratchViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, WScratchView view) {
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        mView = view;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        mRun = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return mSurfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (mRun) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    if (c != null) {
                        mView.draw(c);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void resetView() {
    synchronized (mThread.getSurfaceHolder()) {
        mPathList.clear();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isScratchable() 
{
    return mIsScratchable;
}

@Override
public void setScratchable(boolean flag) {
    mIsScratchable = flag;
}

@Override
public void setOverlayColor(int ResId) {
    mOverlayColor = ResId;
}

@Override
public void setRevealSize(int size) {
    mRevealSize = size;
}

@Override
public void setAntiAlias(boolean flag) {
    mIsAntiAlias = flag;
}


@Override
public void setScratchDrawable(Drawable d) {
    mScratchDrawable = d;
    if (mScratchDrawable != null) {
        mScratchBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mScratchDrawable).getBitmap();
    }
}

@Override
public void setScratchBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    mScratchBitmap = b;
}


@Override
public float getScratchedRatio() {
    return getScratchedRatio(DEFAULT_SCRATCH_TEST_SPEED);
}

/**
 * thanks to https://github.com/daveyfong for providing this method
 */
@Override
public float getScratchedRatio(int speed) {
    if (null == mScratchedTestBitmap) {
        return 0;
    }
    draw(mScratchedTestCanvas);

    final int width = mScratchedTestBitmap.getWidth();
    final int height = mScratchedTestBitmap.getHeight();

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i += speed) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j += speed) {
            if (0 == Color.alpha(mScratchedTestBitmap.getPixel(i, j))) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    float completed = (float) count / ((width / speed) * (height / speed)) * 100;

    return completed;
}

@Override
public void setOnScratchCallback(OnScratchCallback callback) {
    mOnScratchCallback = callback;
}

public static abstract class OnScratchCallback{
    public abstract void onScratch(float percentage);
    //Call back funtion to monitor the status of finger
    public abstract void onDetach(boolean fingerDetach);
}

//Set the mClearCanvas
@Override
public void setScratchAll(boolean scratchAll){
    mClearCanvas = scratchAll;
}

//Set the WScartchView clickable
@Override
public void setBackgroundClickable(boolean clickable){
    mIsClickable = clickable;
}
```

}

and the code for bitmap is as below

```
 gray.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FrameLayout fm = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frmQueue);
            fm.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            fm.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm =fm.getDrawingCache();

            scratchView.setScratchBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Take Screenshot of Surface View Shows Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this piece of code

```
 public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

The calling would be something like

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = loadBitmapFromView(frameLayout, frameLayout.getLayoutParams().width,frameLayout.getLayoutParams().height));
```

Can you use this code for FrameLayout?

```
    FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: i tried this one but it still give me bitmap of only image low. i am not getting bitmap from scratch_image

Comment: i want to get entire bitmap from framlayout but i am still unable to do it

Comment: i cannot do project from scratch do you have any other place to share code like gist of paste bin? so that i can directly look in problecm rather than coding all things...

Comment: my problem is that when i tries to get bitmap from my fram layout i am getting bitmap of only image view which is imagelow, on top of imagelow there is custom surface view and i am loading image in that custom surface view and make some drawing operation on surface view. now after complete operation i need to get the completed image which is in side of fram layout. but when i tries to get bitmap i only get bitmap of imagelow. else if i use WScrathch view to get bitmap i am getting only over image in which i performed operation. while i need the bitmap of combination of both image

Comment: yes i tried that code but it also give me the bitmap of lover image only. i think the problem is that the custom surface view is not getting inside of frame layout. and i cant solve it. i tried this code very first time. but it does not give result.

Comment: last thing i can expect is get shared repo from you or sample code till then fingers crossed XX